# Nodemon --ext any file type

Tags: javascript, build, nodemon

I have an images directory that I want to watch. The directory can have many different file types. I know you can specify a list of file types for nodemon to watch, but how can I tell nodemon to watch ALL files in a directory? My command looks like this right now:

```
"watch-images": "nodemon --ignore build/ -e jpg,png --watch images --exec 'cp -a images/ build/images/'"
```

What can I use to replace the jpg,png?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `nodemon --ext '*'` to watch for all file extensions. It'll output:

```
[nodemon] watching extensions: (all)
```

Mentioned in this feature request:

https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/915#issuecomment-445905946

Comment: is there any way to watch for multiple file extensions, like `ts` and `yml`.

Comment: Just use `nodemon -e ts,yml`

Comment: This didnt work for me it the logs showed `[nodemon] watching extensions: ','` I used `nodemon -e *` instead