# Nodemon doesn't watch for .env files

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I have the following code structure:

```
--src
----config
------env
--------development.env
--------index.js
```

Here's my **nodemon.json** file:

```
{
    "watch": ["src"],
    "events": {
        "start": "cls || clear"
    }
}
```

It works when I make a change to **index.js** file, but when a change made in **development.env** nodemon doesn't get restarted.

I tried the following to make it works but no success:

```
"watch": ["src", "src/config/env/development.env"]
```

Comment: check ignore flag in `nodemon.json` or `ignore` key in `nodemonConfig` in package.json

Comment: Have you tried using the `--ext` [option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739752/7700187)/[property](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md)?

Comment: @Daniel I don't have `nodemonConfig`property in my **package.json**

Comment: @JamesT thanks, `ext: "*"` works